# Easiest way for a beginner to design and make a custom printed circuit

Tags: arduino, pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication

I've used a prototyping board to successfully build an Arduino based system for a custom purpose

I would like to transfer this design to a custom PCB (using a service like PCBWay, for example,) so that I can have a smaller and neater circuit board to mount the components on.

When I went to PCBWay, I found the whole process overwhelming and didn't know what suitable software I (as a beginner) could use to design the board.

I only want to produce 1 or 2 small boards and it's only for my own usage.

[image]

Comment: There are hundreds of tutorials online and on YouTube that cover this, so I would pick one close to what you want to do and learn about the process until it isn't so overwhelming.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Download and use [KiCad](https://www.kicad.org/). It's open source. It's free. Available for Windows, macOS  or Linux and It's **more** than enough for most hobbyists and many commercial users. You could also download a demo of a commercial program such as Altium but it won't be a much different experience, and the demo will time out leaving you without access to modifying your source files unless you fork over thousands of dollars.  Follow some tutorials to get started (there **will** be a frustrating learning curve, expect and embrace it*, but follow the tutorials and you should be there in a few days). A two layer PCB will be fine for what you have. Try to do a ground pour. And consider [Ki-cking](https://www.kicad.org/donate/faq/#:%7E:text=Donating%20to%20KiCad%20via%20The,profit%20organization%20in%20the%20US.) them over few bucks if you're happy with the program.

When you have the PCB the way you like it on the screen you can output gerber files and NC drill file(s), zip them up and upload to your favorite online PCB vendor. These *very* inexpensive online vendors don't (can't) provide a whole lot of hands-on help, so you should read and understand their [help files](https://www.pcbway.com/helpcenter) and take responsibility for what you get, because it's generally what  you asked for (whether you wanted it or not). So you start with an EDA (Electronic Design Automation) program that is intended to produce the outputs that the industry uses, and then your interactions with them will be minimized.

* Someone once told me that when they got frustrated doing something, they got excited because it meant they were about to learn something new.

Comment: The KiCad tutorials by Shawn Hymel are very good.

Comment: @Mattman944 He's a cool young fellow. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/live/ja5HU18KvPk?feature=share) is his talk from last year's Supercon (nothing to do with Kicad, about hacking a toaster). I may or may not be visible in the audience.

Comment: I agree that Kicad is the best choice.  I had never designed a PCB before but had some electronics experience building hobbyist circuits.  I read and watched tutorials and figured out how to create a complete PCB.  My additional advice is to use https://oshpark.com/ and upload your files and keep uploading until you see that it looks correct in preview.  Also, since smaller board footprints are cheaper try to keep it as small as possible and keep it to 2 layers if possible.  Worked for me. Good luck.

Comment: Hopefully this isn't prohibited, since I'm recommending a comparison site and not a specific vendor -- I've had good luck with pcbshopper.com, to find a vendor that can do what I need for a good price, for a small run, in a reasonable time, etc

Answer (score 5):

Here's a second for kicad or eagle cad, whenever you use see if the parts are already in the library or if you can get a library so you don't have to manually enter in footprints or reduce that work as much as possible.

Make sure you double and triple check the schematic to the footprint otherwise you'll end up with the board that doesn't work and you'll have to do another revision which takes time and money.

Also think about connectors polarity and pins and clearly mark the polarity and function on the silk screen

Answer (score 3):

Whatever PCB software you use you'll need components in your schematic and footprint library. Building these takes a long time so don't. Use existing libraries and these can be found many places but Library Loader is a great source. Do due diligence and always check both the footprint size and pinout is correct before you order the PCB as anyone can produce and share dud library files.

Answer (score 1):

If you start with something simpler, you can learn all the steps, and then apply them to something more complex. I had no experience but put together and ordered this, https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEuJb.jpg, by following a lecture on KiCad and then designed it with KiCad and ordered it with jlcpcb.com. The hardest part seem to be the "footprints" since you can choose from so many parts. I used similar footprints to lecture I followed, and also used ChatGPT to get some tips on footprints.

Answer (score 0):

KiCad is great for sure. But you might want to checkout EasyEDA also. If memory serves me their online app does it all and might be easier for you the first time out with this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I need a circuit board I went to the local community college, where they teach printed circuit making.  The result was a useless disaster, as if a vulgar and brutal member of the football team made it as a nasty joke on a brainy electronic nerd.

Then I went online to Alberta Printed Circuits.  Download their software, use it to lay out your traces, and upload the resulting files.  Your PC board will be shipped withing 24 hours if they are still in business.  On a road trip I happened through Calgary and visited their impressive facility.  It was all done by one person.